# URL of a static site

Tags: html, ruby, url, browser, jekyll

I am working to develop my portfolio, a static site using Jekyll and ruby. When I first served it, I got the URL that went something like localhost:4000 as an output in the terminal.
Afterwards, I would pin the tab, and continue making changes to it.
But mistakenly, I closed the tab and the link from the history of the browser doesn't seem to work.
Can anyone help me get back the link?
I did try "cd myblog"
then, "bundle exec jekyll serve"
But this doesn't work.
[image]
[image]

Comment: The error message clearly says that your YAML has a syntax problem on line 38, column 3.

Comment: Also, don't post images of your code or errors. Always paste the relevant information into your question as a quote or code block.

Comment: Thankyou @ToddA.Jacobs for the suggestion. I found the way to go about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Jekyll QuickStart](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/) guide:

1. Change into your directory, e.g.:

   ```
   cd myblog
   ```
2. Build the site and make it available on a local server.

   ```
   bundle exec jekyll serve
   ```
3. Browse to http://localhost:4000

Comment: I edited the question so that you see that the above approach doesn't work. Please suggest something that can be done.